# KDevelop4 Debugging {...} cannot be unfolded

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, ide, kdevelop

I am debugging with KDevelop4 which is not showing Types always in its variables window and also Its showing `{...}` instead of unfolding the data. Is there any way to unfold ? and see types of all variables ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

KDevelop supports [gdb pretty printers](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Pretty-Printing.html) for prettier showing variable contents. If `matrix` is your own class you can write a pretty printer yourself. If you use some library you might find pretty printers for it - or write one yourself too.

Note that gdb pretty printers also work when debugging gdb cli.

Comment: forget about matrix. its just an `std::map` and `_connection` is just an `std::vector` and I don't need pretty printer. It would be enough to see the unpretty output. but `{...}` means no output at all

Comment: std::map should be supported. Please create a bugreport on bugs.kde.org so we can track down this issue. Enable gdb debug area in kdebugdialog and post the console output in your report.

Answer (score 0):

I just enabled the pretty printers in gdb and now also run into this problem. You can fix this by disabling the pretty printer. Check `/etc/gdb/gdbinit/` and `~/.gdbinit`. Then you can expand `_matrix` to see the `std::map` implementation variables. Though I doubt they would be very useful.